# Player doesn't move after being spawned

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, unity-game-engine

I'm currently working on a tactical RPG and I have the following issue:

When the player is destroyed, he is spawned at a specific position in the grid. However, after being spawned he doesn't move.

I'm using this script to destroy the player and spawn him. It's attached to each player in the game:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Jogador : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Mapa mapa;

    public Vector2Int GridPosition;

    public bool isPlayer = false;

    public float Health = 50f;

    public GameObject SpawnPoint;


    private void Awake()
    {
        if (!mapa) mapa = FindObjectOfType<Mapa>();
    }
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        foreach (var tile in mapa.GridMatriz)
        {
            //tile.jogador = this;
        }

    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            RaycastHit hit;
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit) && hit.transform == this.transform)
            {
                mapa.GetComponent<Movimentação>().TurnEnd();
                isPlayer = true;
                mapa.GetComponent<Movimentação>().TurnStart();
                Debug.Log("clicked");
            }

        }
            CheckHealth();
    }

    public void CheckHealth()// Function to check the player's health
    {
        if (Health <= 0)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
            Instantiate(this, Spawnador.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the movement script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;
public class Movimentação : MonoBehaviour
{
    //player variables
    public GameObject player;
    public GameObject[] Personagens;

    //moving variables
    Vector3 targetPosition;
    float posY = 1;
    public float velocity = 0.2f;
    public float movMax = 3;
    public bool ismoving = false;
    public bool moveEnabled;
    public int aux;

    //bullet variables
    public GameObject projetil;
    private GameObject SpawBala;
    public float ProjetilVeloc = 500f;

    private void Start()
    {
        //sets the first unit as the active unit at the start of the game
        Personagens[0].GetComponent<Jogador>().isPlayer = true;
        TurnStart();

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        //left mouse button to start movement
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            //raycast checks and returns an object, if it's a tile, the unit moves
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            RaycastHit hit;
            ismoving = true;

            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
            {
                if (hit.transform.tag == "Tile")
                {
                    //checks if the tile is available based on the max movement of the unit
                    Tile tileAux = hit.transform.gameObject.GetComponent<Tile>();
                    Jogador scriptJog = player.GetComponent<Jogador>();
                    if ((tileAux.TilePostion.x - scriptJog.GridPosition.x) + (tileAux.TilePostion.y - scriptJog.GridPosition.y) >= -movMax && (tileAux.TilePostion.x - scriptJog.GridPosition.x) + (tileAux.TilePostion.y - scriptJog.GridPosition.y) <= movMax)
                    {
                        if ((tileAux.TilePostion.x - scriptJog.GridPosition.x) - (tileAux.TilePostion.y - scriptJog.GridPosition.y) >= -movMax && (tileAux.TilePostion.x - scriptJog.GridPosition.x) - (tileAux.TilePostion.y - scriptJog.GridPosition.y) <= movMax)
                        {
                            targetPosition = (hit.transform.position);
                            targetPosition.y = posY;
                            moveEnabled = true;
                        }

                    }
                }
            }

        }

        //right click to shoot
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1))
        {
            //raycast checks and returns an object, if it's a tile, the unit shoots
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            RaycastHit hit;

            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
            {
                //checks if the tile is available based on the line and column of the unit
                Tile tileAux = hit.transform.gameObject.GetComponent<Tile>();
                Jogador scriptJog = player.GetComponent<Jogador>();

                if (tileAux.TilePostion.x == scriptJog.GridPosition.x || tileAux.TilePostion.y == scriptJog.GridPosition.y)
                {
                    if (tileAux.TilePostion.x > scriptJog.GridPosition.x)
                        tileAux.TilePostion.x = 5;
                    else
                        tileAux.TilePostion.x = 0;

                    if (tileAux.TilePostion.y > scriptJog.GridPosition.y)
                        tileAux.TilePostion.y = 5;
                    else
                        tileAux.TilePostion.y = 0;

                    Debug.Log(tileAux.TilePostion.x);
                    Debug.Log(tileAux.TilePostion.y);

                    //instantiates the bullet
                    GameObject tiro = Instantiate(projetil, SpawBala.transform.position, SpawBala.transform.rotation);
                    Rigidbody BalaRigid = tiro.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

                    if (SpawBala.tag == "Bala1")
                    {
                        BalaRigid.AddForce(Vector3.forward * ProjetilVeloc);

                    }

                    if (SpawBala.tag == "Bala2")
                    {
                        BalaRigid.AddForce(Vector3.back * ProjetilVeloc);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        //player moves until reaches the position
        if (player.transform.position != targetPosition)
        {
            player.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(player.transform.position, targetPosition, velocity);
            if (player.transform.position == targetPosition)
                ismoving = false;
        }

        //if player reaches position, it's deselected
        if (moveEnabled && !ismoving)
        {
            player.GetComponent<Jogador>().isPlayer = false;
            moveEnabled = false;
        }
    }

    public void TurnStart()
    {
        //makes the selected unit the active unit
        for (int i = 0; i < Personagens.Length; i++)
        {
            if (Personagens[i].GetComponent<Jogador>().isPlayer == true)
            {
                player = Personagens[i];
                posY = player.transform.position.y;
                targetPosition = player.transform.position;
                SpawBala = player.transform.GetChild(0).gameObject;
            }
        }
    }

    public void TurnEnd()
    {
        //desactivates all units
        for (int i = 0; i < Personagens.Length; i++)
        {
            Personagens[i].GetComponent<Jogador>().isPlayer = false;
        }
    }
}
```

I really don't know what's going on guys.

Comment: Instantiate(this, Spawnador.transform.position, Quaternion.identity); ?? this should be a prefab.. not an active gameobject, Im surprised kinda that anything spawns.  the movement script seems odd too, as if thats on the spawned object, it resets the item in position 0 in personagens to player, its hard to tell whats going on here .. Id suggest a lot of debug messages

Comment: I've tried to use a prefab, but it didn't work as well

Comment: Then you need a butt load of debug messages and it should be a prefab so all the script components need to be on the prefab

Comment: Thank you man, now I could solve the problem. The player wasn't move, because I wasn't resentting the health to 50 again.